']' expected error when trying to index array
soo recently i'm making mod for minecraft, and i decided to sort items in arrays to later use them in assignment, soo i made this:

import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack;
import org.lwjgl.system.windows.MONITORINFOEX;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface CreativeTabsItems {
    String[] tutorialTabItems = new String[1];
    tutorialTabItems[0] = "tutorial:rock";
}


when i'm trying to run this, it gives me ']' expected error and points 0 index, anyone knows how to fix that?
i searched on reddit, also on forums and stackoverflow but nothing

What you expect this code to do?

Remove all those imports. You don't need any. And make sure your array initialization code is inside a method.

you cannot write statements outside of a method (or initializer block); field declarations with optional initialization are allowed (e.g. String[] tutorialTabItems = { "tutorial:rock" };)

@Anonymous but you can have class constants (there is no way to even try to add an instance variable since a field will implicitly be declared public, static and final {and there is no unstatic  keyword})

@user85421 Thanks, that’s new to me (and ugly IMHO, I had not really needed to know). So the OP may combine the two lines into public static final String[] tutorialTabItems = { "tutorial:rock" }; (with or without the redundant public static final) and be set. I giess you could posted that as an answer had the question not been closed.

You are declaring an interface - this is mainly meant for method declarations, sometimes for constants (but that is a questionable use).
You probably want to use a class instead, and do the initialization and fill of the array in its constructor.
Maybe you should take a Java tutorial like the one from Oracle - note that it is quite old, but for starting with Java it could help you. Or search for any modern online Java learning - I can't really recommend one as I know the language for a long time now and didn't take any courses on it recently. It will pay off the time if you learned the basics properly and in a structured way!

but even in a class you cannot have statements outside a method or initializer block

@user85421 exactly, that's why I wrote "and do the initialization and fill of the array in its constructor".

i made array inside interface, but then i call methood on program start to fill it

Declaring constants in an interface is not questionable. The old practice of implementing interfaces to import the names of the constants was. So, if the constants logically belong to the interface, there’s nothing wrong with that.
